# Match nested array if it is empty or contains value mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I have a nested array stored and I would like to match items where either the array is empty or it contains a specific value.
I can do both of them separately but I cannot figure it out to perform both these filters

The schema is as follows:

```
{
   ...
   mapping:{
     User:[],
     Test:["test"]
   }
}
```

Comment: This might https://mongoplayground.net/p/rKZ492oiDfq help you

Comment: Thanks but I needed in inside an $or with other conditions so this wouldn't work however turns out we can sinply do `"mapping.Test": { $in: [ [],"test" ]  }`